# Python Flask Bokeh update using AJAX

Tags: python, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I have bokeh plot which I like to insert in my HTML using Jquery. 
In Flask, I generate the bokeh plot and return the component in AJAX call-

```
`@app.route('/show_graph' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_graph():
    input_data = request.get_json()
    plot = fc.generate_graph(input_data) # get bokeh plot here
    script, div = components(plot)

    return jsonify(script= script, div = div)`
```

How to add this component in HTML div?

```
$('#cali_').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                data = project_data;


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/show_graph',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function(callback) {

                        script = callback.script;
                        div = callback.dive;

                        // I have a div element with id= "graph"
                        //Here I want to update HTML with bokeh graph

                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#graph").html(callback.div);`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that did not work. Thanks for the question.